# html5 video banner - width issue

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make a full width banner using html5 video I want the width to be 100vw and height roughly 400px this was my attempt;

```
min-width: 100vw;
width: auto; 
z-index: -100;
background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
overflow: none;
```

It didn't quite work its just full screen with overflow bars on x & y, anyone know how I can achieve this effect.

If I add a hight of 400px it just removes the video width

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this your HTML would look like

```
<video controls>
  <source src="filename.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

And then your CSS would be

```
video {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: -100;
    background: red; /* Replace with the path to your background image
    overflow: none;
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rUFH5/)

Comment: Hey, this centers the video and creates a full width background image with the video in the center

Comment: @user2598957 Can you create a demo?

Comment: Sure 2 seconds I will upload the video to add to a fiddle